# Uninstalled and re-installed Android Studio and now I can't open any of my projects

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I was having issues with gradle builds, so I decided to uninstall android studio and I installed it again and whenever I try to open one of my projects, I cannot see the actual project layout anymore. This is all I see when I try to open up one of my past projects:

[image]

Did I screw something up? I am opening my projects the same exact way that I did before I uninstalled it. What could be the problem?

Comment: miriad problems, are you using AS `3.1.1` ? if not why not ? Android plugin 3.1.1 ? Gradle version 4.4? platform ? Are we supposed to **guess** what what you are doing ? **Help us**, help yourself...Please be specific...

Comment: AS 3.1.1 How do I check all that other info?

Comment: By research, this site does not give dispensation to anyone, show your working....

Comment: What do you mean it's broken? Maybe that is the issue I was having before I uninstalled it. It would randomly give me build errors.

Comment: I see this type of listing when gradle has not completed build and indexing has not completed. You should ensure that gradle build is completed, see in message or gradle, there should not be any issue.

Comment: No i have not read that. That's cool if you have resolved this.

Comment: All your projects showing same error?

Comment: I got it fixed. I had to add a bunch of plugins.